# Rails 3: Create new rails asset helper like image_tag that points to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

What would be the best way to create a new asset tag helper that would work the exact same way as image_tag, except pointed to s3?

So I'd like this to happen:

```
image_path "foo.jpg" # => "/assets/foo.jpg" (default behavior)
s3_image_path "bar.jpg" # => "http://site.s3.amazon.com/assets/bar.jpg"
```

Would the best way to do this be just to make a new helper in application_helper.rb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ended up writing new helpers in application_helper.rb that mimicked the default asset helpers like so:

```
def s3_image_path(filename)
  "http://site.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/#{filename}"
end

def s3_image_tag(filename, options={})
  image_tag(s3_image_path(filename), options)
end
```

So `s3_image_tag("image.jpg")` will point to `http://site.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/image.jpg`.

Comment: This is great. I wonder how you deal with asset precompile syncing with S3 though?

Answer (score 0):

If site.s3.. is not in the rails application and not using the asset_pipeline, then just reference the url directly in the image src.

If s3 is your application site, then yes just a write a new helper in the context it will be used for.

Or something for http://site.s3.amazon.com/assets/bar.jpg would look like

```
<img src="<%=@root_url%>/assets/bar.jpg" />
```

So, why is the other one different?  I mean why do you have two?

**Edit:**

What I would do is just have a string holding the url to the hosted site in the application helper.  Then the helper method to return the image  `tag("img", :src => "#{s3_image_link}/bar.jpg")`

Comment: The idea is it would be cleaner to have a separate image helper that points to a static asset hosted on Amazon when that image doesn't need to go through the asset pipeline. I could just use the direct Amazon URL but it's long and ugly and makes me sad.